# GUI SFTP client for Linux which maintains an open session

Tags: linux, file-management, gui, sftp

I use LXDE, whose file manager - pcmanfm - supports SFTP, but does not keep an open session, so when I want to drill down to a directory I have to wait repeatedly for connection establishment.

I would like to have something like WinSCP on Windows - an application which maintains an open SSH/SFTP session. Obviously, the `sftp` utility can do this when I'm on the command-line - but I want to be able to do this in a GUI environment.

**Notes:**

- Desirable feature: TCP keepalives and/or no-effect commands for the connection to stay up.
- Desirable feature: File and directory drag-and-drop support.
- desktop-environment-specific solutions are *appreciated* and perhaps even preferred because of their integration with the rest of the UI; specifically, KDE- and LXDE-specific apps/utilities/UI components.

Comment: Would a text-mode UI do? I'm using *Midnight Commander*, which deals with this using [FISH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol).

Comment: @Izzy: No... I like mc, but not for this purpose.

Comment: Have you looked at [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org)?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax I was going to suggest Filezilla too, but it doesn't supports keep alives for SFTP. It does for plain FTP and FTPS, though.